# TSQL Group By Sum Where Like And > - the sum of all products that contain '%x%' > y, pull grouped keyid - Volusion - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, volusion

### SQL Server 2008 - This is my standard export

### OrderDetailID - OrderID - ProductName - TotalPrice - ShipDate

```
34                     16           Green...           5.00        4/9/16
35                     16           Green...           3.00        4/9/16
36                     16           Blue...            8.00        4/9/16
37                     17           Green...           9.00        4/11/16
38                     17           Red...             3.00        4/11/16
39                     18           Blue...            5.00        4/11/16
40                     19           Green...           4.00        4/11/16
41                     19           Red...             6.00        4/11/16
42                     20           Green...           3.00        4/11/16
43                     20           Green...           3.00        4/11/16
```

I need an output of all OrderIDs that contain a total sum >= 5.00 for green products bought today. (Think of it as a Saint Patricks Day Sale, buy 5.00$ worth of green items, qualify for output.)

End result would be:

---

### OrderID

17

20

I know I can do this in excel, but having me do it every day is not something I want. Luckily, I have access to a built-in API which allows me to set stored SQL queries, so if I can find out how to word this, theoretically anyone should be able to click 1 button and get the results they desire (based on me editing the criteria as needed, ie: green, >5, ect)

So far i'm around something like this

```
SELECT table.OrderID
WHERE table.ProductName LIKE '%green%'
AND SUM(table.TotalPrice) > 5 
GROUP BY table.OrderID
FROM table
```

It just keeps coming back

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Maybe someone will answer, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, and if I figure this out I'll make sure to update.

Comment: learn sql syntax before writing queries.

Comment: I'm an excel junkie by day, but a question was proposed to me about a SQL query. I'm not a DBA or software engineer or anything, so I just needed a little push in the right direction. Had some trouble wrapping my head around this simple process which I know I can logically execute in excel, just didn't know the syntax like you said or how to word it, but I figured i'd ask why my logic is failing before learning SQL completely. Turns out the where function is limited! Appreciate the concern though, and I would not say I can write SQL, so you are completely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  table.OrderID
FROM    table
WHERE   table.ProductName LIKE '%green%'
GROUP BY
        table.OrderID
HAVING  SUM(table.TotalPrice) >= 5
```

Comment: Having! Much appreciated, incredible response time. This place is full of the best :)